# Sum of bernoulli random variables

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

suppose Z is a random variable which is the sum of some random variables with bernoulli distribution:

$Z=Z_1+Z_2+...+Z_m $ , $Z_i \in \{0,1\} ,$ $Pr(Z_i=1)=p=1-1/2^k$ or $1/2^k$ when k is an integer greater than 1.

then what is the probability of $Pr(Z\geq m/2)$?

I know that the sum of bernoulli variables is a binomial variable but I cannot find an answer for this probability:

$Pr(Z\geq m/2)= {\Sigma}_{i=m/2}^{m} C(m,i) \cdot p^i \cdot (1-p)^{n-i} =?$

Comment: $p = 1−(1/2)^k\quad$ What is 'k' ?

Comment: @georg , k is a number greater than 1.

Comment: So unfortunately - I can not advise.